# How can I upload my Eclipse Android project to GitHub?

Tags: android, eclipse, github, repository, project

I have an Android project set up in my Eclipse workspace. What I would like would be if this individual project could be set up in its own Git repository. I tried to do this previously but I ended up having a huge file because all of my workspace projects ended up on this one repo. This caused problems when I uploaded my APK to the Google Play store. (It was something like 20MB instead of 2MB).

Any ideas as to how I would be able to do this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You apparently made your whole workspace into a git repo

1. Delete/backup your repo (the workspace/.git folder)
2. Go to github and create a new repo - say you name it `my-project`
3. Install [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=full%20installer%20official%20git). You *will* have to work with it sooner or later
4. Right click on your **project** folder and choose Git Bash here
5. Issue

   ```
   $ git init
   $ echo bin/ >> .gitignore # exclude the bin folder !
   $ git add -A && git commit -m "All my files" # this will commit *all*
   # better fire up the gui and choose what to commit
   $ git remote add origin https://github.com/YOURUSERNAME/my-project.git
   $ git push -u origin master
   ```

Done